# NoClassDefFoundError: ..FRLayout, hosting Applet

Tags: java, applet

I have created an applet, which i aim to put online, i have created the HTML code for it and put the class files in the area, and i am running into issues, my applet uses the JUNG library, and i have been putting all the files individually up on to the web-space in the corresponding folders (I cannot put the whole library on the web-space as i do not have enough space)

However after going through many and getting the hang of putting them all in the right location, i am now stuck.

I have located what i believe is the right file ie FRLayout.class from the JUNG library and put it into the directory: edu/uci/jung/algorithms/layout/ however when i do and i try to run the applet i get the corresponding error:

```
RunTimeException:

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: edu/uci/jung/algorithms/layout/FRLayout (wrong name: edu/uci/jung/algorithms/layout3d/FRLayout)
```

Now this path directory actually does not exist on my webspace? and i have tried putting the file in here just in case that works but it didn't.

i wondered whether i had got the 3d version of the FRLayout, but i have checked the folders and i don't believe it is, i have also re-extracted the Jar file, but to no avail.

Really stuck
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

---

I have tried both the 3d and non-3d versions in the layout folder, however both provide me with the same runtime exception.

Really could use some advice, Thanks

Comment: Where does the 3D version come from?  It is not listed [here](http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/layout/package-summary.html).  Why code an applet?  If it is due to spec. by teacher, please refer them to [Why CS teachers should stop teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/).  A frame launched from a link using JWS provides a better ser experience.

Comment: In the Jung library there is a separate jar file that has the 3d version, but that's exactly it, i have no idea why it's even relating to it. 
I am doing an applet as just a way to show what work I've done.

Comment: *"I am doing an applet as just a way to show what work I've done."*  That work will be a ***lot*** more with an applet.  *"In the Jung library there is a separate jar file that has the 3d version"*  Where are the JavaDocs for it?  What is the name of the Jar in which that class is located?  What is the applet element used to launch it? ..

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javadocs&oq=javadocs&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j5.1753j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=javadocs+jung+graph3d >Then click> JUNG API Javadoc (version 2.0) >Then click> edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.layout3d. that's for the 3D version, although im still confused why it even comes into the error. My work is already within Applet, its just the fact id like to be able to put it on the web.

Comment: *"My work is already within Applet, its just the fact id like to be able to put it on the web."*  Yep.  That last part of 'put on the web' is where all the extra work (and trouble) comes in.  Have you been following the slew of problems that recent security updates have caused applets?  That is just the last in a long (long..) line of applet/JRE/browser interaction problems.  Some of those problems also occur for 'frame launched from link', and some of the problems with this launch need to be fixed for either way of launch, but take it from someone that deals with both.  Applet is way harder..

Comment: Difficult to identify the root cause until you paste the full stacktrace. This may give some pointers - http://javareferencegv.blogspot.com/2013/10/debugging-javalangnoclassdeffounderror.html